# How I can suppress the unwanted pulse in a signal?

Tags: vhdl, digital

I am getting a signal from sensor, which is having glitches in the signal. I need to calculate the time period of each pulse.

If a pulse is shorter than or equal to 1 microsecond, I have to ignore that.

If a pulse is longer than 1 microsecond, I have to use that pulse.

I'm using VHDL.

Comment: See [ask] and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Show us what you have so far. You can measure each pulse, and compare with 1 µs.

Comment: You appear to be describing a [debouncer](https://forum.digikey.com/t/debounce-logic-circuit-vhdl/12573).

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to implement a counter that is enabled by the signal and reset when the signal is 0. Determining if a signal is longer than a microsecond will require knowing your clock period.

Let's assume you have a 10MHz clock, so a clock period of 1/10MHz = 100ns (or 0.1us). If you start a timer when the input signal goes high, you know that the signal is at least 1us when the counter reaches 10.

I could be wrong, but this sounds like a school problem to me. Based on the exact wording of the question, your teacher may want you to wait until the counter reaches 11, since 10 could be called "equal" to 1us. I would argue this is unnecessary, as statistically the probability of a 1us pulse lining up *perfectly* with your counter is zero.

Since this sounds like a school problem to me, I'm not going to write out a complete answer, but I'll give you something to start the counter with.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity pulse_counter is
  port (
    i_clk           : std_logic;
    i_pulse         : std_logic;
    o_count         : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
  );
end entity pulse_counter;

architecture rtl of pulse_counter is
  signal count  : unsigned(7 downto 0);
begin
  process(i_clk)
  begin
    if(rising_edge(i_clk)) then
      if(i_pulse = '1') then
        count <= count + 1;
      else
        count <= (others => '0');
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

  o_count <= std_logic_vector(count);
end architecture rtl;
```

Note that I didn't simulate this, so it is possible there are bugs.